# How i can count count of doc_id, which has every word in dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I have pandas dataframe whith 2 columns. 
This dataframe shows, in which document (doc_id) occurs word. One word may occurs in several documents.

```
doc_id  word
1       One
1       Two
1       Three
1       John
2       One
2       John
2       Eva
3       One
3       Eva
```

I want to get dataframe, which shows the count of documents, in which every word occurs, and the share of this indicator (100*count of documents/total_count_of_documetns), sorted by count.

So, the result must be as following dataframe:

```
word  doc_count   share
One       3       100%
John      2       66.67%
Eva       2       66.67%
Two       1       33.33%
Three     1       33.33%
```

How I can make it whith pandas in Python?

Comment: `df.groupby('word')['doc_id'].nunique()` and the divide that with `df['doc_id'].nuquie()`?

Comment: USe `df.groupby('word').agg(doc_count=('doc_id', 'nunique')).assign(share=lambda s: s['doc_count']/s['doc_count'].max() * 100).sort_values('doc_count', ascending=False)`